# Where did these .tmp files come from?

Tags: c++, r, armadillo

Firstly, some details:

- I am using a combination of C++ ([Armadillo library](http://arma.sourceforge.net/)) and R.
- I am using Ubuntu as my operating system.
- I am **not** using [Rcpp](http://www.rcpp.org)

Suppose that I have some C++ code called *cpp_code* which:

- Reads, as input from R, an integer,
- Performs some calculations,
- Saves, as output to R, a spreadsheet "out.csv". (I use [.save( name, file_type = csv)](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#save_load_field))

Some simplified R code would be:

```
for(i in 1:10000)
{
 system(paste0("echo ", toString(i), " | ./cpp_code")) ## produces out.csv
 output[i,,] <- read.csv("out.csv") ## reads out.csv
}
```

**My Problem:**

99% of the time, everything works fine. However, every now and then, I keep getting some unusual .tmp files like: "out.csv.tmp_a0ac9806ff7f0000703a". These .tmp files only appear for a second or so, then suddenly disappear.

Questions:

- What is causing this?
- Is there a way to stop this from happening?

Please go easy on me since computing is not my main discipline.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Can you explain why you prefer to write the data to a file and read it back into R, when RcppArmadillo would allow the same Armadillo code to pass the data back to R?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many programs write their output to a temporary file, then rename it to the destination file. This is often done to avoid leaving a half-written output file if the process is killed while writing. By using a temporary, the file can be atomically renamed to the output file name ensuring either:

- the entire output file is properly written or
- no change is made to the output file

Note there usually are still some race conditions that could result, for example, in the output file being deleted but the temporary file not renamed, but one of the two outcomes above is the general goal.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you're using `.save` function in `armadillo`.

http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#save_load_field

There are two functions you should see in
`include/armadillo_bits/diskio_meat.hpp`. In `save_raw_ascii`, it first stores data to the filename from `diskio::gen_tmp_name`, and if `save_okay`, rename by `safe_rename`. If `safe_okay` or `safe_rename` failed, you will see temporary file. The temporary file name is chosen as `filename + .tmp_ + some hex value from file name`.

```
//! Save a matrix as raw text (no header, human readable).
//! Matrices can be loaded in Matlab and Octave, as long as they don't have complex elements.
template<typename eT>
inline
bool
diskio::save_raw_ascii(const Mat<eT>& x, const std::string& final_name)
  {
  arma_extra_debug_sigprint();

  const std::string tmp_name = diskio::gen_tmp_name(final_name);

  std::fstream f(tmp_name.c_str(), std::fstream::out);

  bool save_okay = f.is_open();

  if(save_okay == true)
    {
    save_okay = diskio::save_raw_ascii(x, f);

    f.flush();
    f.close();

    if(save_okay == true)
      {
      save_okay = diskio::safe_rename(tmp_name, final_name);
      }
    }

  return save_okay;
  }

//! Append a quasi-random string to the given filename.
//! The rand() function is deliberately not used,
//! as rand() has an internal state that changes
//! from call to call. Such states should not be
//! modified in scientific applications, where the
//! results should be reproducable and not affected 
//! by saving data.
inline
std::string
diskio::gen_tmp_name(const std::string& x)
  {
  const std::string* ptr_x     = &x;
  const u8*          ptr_ptr_x = reinterpret_cast<const u8*>(&ptr_x);

  const char* extra      = ".tmp_";
  const uword extra_size = 5;

  const uword tmp_size   = 2*sizeof(u8*) + 2*2;
        char  tmp[tmp_size];

  uword char_count = 0;

  for(uword i=0; i<sizeof(u8*); ++i)
    {
    conv_to_hex(&tmp[char_count], ptr_ptr_x[i]);
    char_count += 2;
    }

  const uword x_size = static_cast<uword>(x.size());
  u8 sum = 0;

  for(uword i=0; i<x_size; ++i)
    {
    sum += u8(x[i]);
    }

  conv_to_hex(&tmp[char_count], sum);
  char_count += 2;

  conv_to_hex(&tmp[char_count], u8(x_size));


  std::string out;
  out.resize(x_size + extra_size + tmp_size);


  for(uword i=0; i<x_size; ++i)
    {
    out[i] = x[i];
    }

  for(uword i=0; i<extra_size; ++i)
    {
    out[x_size + i] = extra[i];
    }

  for(uword i=0; i<tmp_size; ++i)
    {
    out[x_size + extra_size + i] = tmp[i];
    }

  return out;
  }
```

Comment: It’s worth noting that the explanatory comment on `gen_tmp_name` is somewhat bogus (you wouldn’t use `rand` in a scientific application anyway, for the exact reason given here, and in addition because it creates crappy random numbers), and that they should probably have used an operating system function to generate a temporary file anyway.

Comment: Each operating system has its own function for creating temporary files, and Armadillo is meant to be platform independent. The quality of `std::rand()` is dependant on the operating system. There's currently no other choice in C++ that provides the same functionality as `std::rand()` and is supported on every operating system. The C++11 built-in random number facility is problematic, as at the very minimum it requires the use of `thread_local`, which is currently not widely supported by various compilers. It looks like only the just released gcc 4.9 supports it properly.

Answer (score 0):

What “Dark Falcon” hypothesises is exactly true: when calling `save`, Armadillo creates a temporary file to which it saves the data, and then renames the file to the final name.

This can be seen [in the source code](http://sourceforge.net/p/arma/code/HEAD/tree/branch-4.300/include/armadillo_bits/diskio_meat.hpp#l857) (this is `save_raw_ascii` but the other `save*` functions work analogously):

```
const std::string tmp_name = diskio::gen_tmp_name(final_name);

std::fstream f(tmp_name.c_str(), std::fstream::out);
  
bool save_okay = f.is_open();
  
if(save_okay == true)
  {
  save_okay = diskio::save_raw_ascii(x, f);
   
  f.flush();
  f.close();
    
  if(save_okay == true)
    {
    save_okay = diskio::safe_rename(tmp_name, final_name);
    }
  }
```

The comment on `safe_rename` says this:

> Safely rename a file.
> Before renaming, test if we can write to the final file.
> This should prevent:
>
> 1. overwriting files that are write protected,
> 2. overwriting directories.

It’s worth noting that this will however **not** prevent a race condition.